# How to Join a data source using a `Like` `LEFT`

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I first created a SQL query and now I'm converting it into an *AOT* query in **AX 2012 R3**. I have everything else working except for one thing. I have a join in my SQL that is: `JOIN dbo.INVENTJOURNALTABLE AS INV3 ON INV.INVENTBATCHID LIKE left(INV3.DESCRIPTION,17)`. In SQL this works and returns the data that I need.

I don't know how to create this `join` in the *AOT* query though.

That `INV3.DESCRIPTION` is a string that contains the *InventBatchID*.

Is there a way to do this kind of *join*?

Comment: Why are you removing the `x++` tag? That is the language that `AX 2012 R3` is programmed in and the language you will need to answer the question about your query?

Comment: @AlexKwitny I'm not using X++, this is an AOT query so I won't be using X++ to answer the question.

Comment: `X++` is required to do what you want, even with a query object. Trust me you should just leave the tag it's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish what you want with a `Query` object, it's difficult/unusual, and AX isn't designed to do this in a straight forward way and requires a very creative solution.

I would generally push towards writing a pure `x++` query as I don't believe `LEFT` and `LIKE` can be natively combined, especially in a query. You can use `*` in the value for "like" as an option.

You may be able to accomplish using [expressions in query ranges](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges) somehow.

If you **must** have a query, a way I can think is by combining a `View`, `Computed Column`, and a `Query`...and I can't guarantee it will work, but I can give you enough to have something to test with. Some of the information in this answer is pretty concentrated so look closely at everything to understand it.

Create a `View`, add the below computed column, then add it to a `Query` as pictured below. For the computed column, you need to add a new `String` field to the view and set the `ViewMethod` property to the name of the method. [See here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/walkthrough-add-a-computed-column-to-a-view) about adding `Computed Columns`.

The `Computed Column` accomplishes the `left(..., 17)` part and you can browse the view to confirm.

The last part is trying to join either by a `relation` (pictured below, but it does not accomplish the `like`) or setting the `Value` property using an expression by following the link above. You may need to create a custom expression in `\Classes\SysQueryRangeUtil`. You have some experimenting to do to see if it works.

[image]

```cs
private static server str compColDescLeft()
{
    #define.ViewName(InventJournalTableView)
    #define.DataSourceName("InventJournalTable_1")
    #define.FieldDescription("Description")
    #define.LeftCount("17")

    str             sReturn;
    str             sLeftDesc;
    DictView        dictView;

    dictView = new DictView(tableNum(#ViewName));

    sLeftDesc = dictView.computedColumnString(#DataSourceName, #FieldDescription, FieldNameGenerationMode::FieldList, true);

    sReturn = "left(" + sLeftDesc + ", " + #LeftCount + ")";

    return sReturn;
}
```